# Spring Boot yaml configuration doesn't load second key

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm trying to create a config file in yaml for my Spring Boot project.

For a test I just setup some values:

```
user:
  test: hello
```

Now I'm trying to get the information of `user.test`, but I get the error message `Could not resolve placeholder 'user.test' in value "${user.test}"`

The strange thing is, that if my config files just has `user.test: hello`, then everything works fine.

Is there something that I have to setup before to work with yml files as properties?

Comment: Is this in your `application.yml` or are you trying to load it yourself...

Comment: I'm loading it with `@PropertySource("file:./users.yml")`

Comment: `@PropertySource` doesn't load YAML files it will treat it as a regular `.properties` file. Either add the properties to the `application.yml` (recommended) or use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` together with the `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` to load the YAML file into properties and add an additional `PropertySource` to the `Environment`.

Comment: I have two properties. One for deeper configurations (application.yml) and one which can be easily be access in the root path. Do you have maybe an example for your suggestion? :)

Comment: why `application.yml` can be used as well. Spring Boot has very lenient loading rules for configuration files.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that. But now I need a solution for lists and maps.